# Check two strings with HBS (express-handlebars)

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm trying to compare two different Strings by HBS.

The function look like this:

```
hbs.registerHelper('if_equal', function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this)
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this)
    } 
});
```

Works great!
But the problem is in this lines:

```
{{#each info.categories}}
    <li><a href="{{this.title}}">{{this.title}}</a></li>
    {{!-- {{#if_equal this.title "מלגזות"}}

    {{/if_equal}} --}}
{{/each}}
```

s you can see I'm trying check if two string are equal  inside the loop.
The problem is how I can back to {{info}} one.
To the global object inside the loop.
And than make loop into the object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to access `info` in the loop you can do it by `@root.info`

https://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#data-root

Comment: I try that:

hbs.registerHelper('if_equal', function(a, b, opts) {
    // if (a == b) {
    //     return opts.fn(this)
    // } else {
    //     return opts.inverse(this)
    // }
    b.forEach((key, value) => {
       if(key.parentName === a){ 
           return opts.fn(this);
       } else {
            return opts.inverse(this);
       }
    })
});

But nothing back!
If i console i hava result!